# Node.js server + Angular 6 client on Azure Functions: handle multi-part form data correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to upload a zip file from an Angular client to the node.js server, both client and server are running as Azure functions in an Azure function app.

Locally, i am using multer package to handle the zip upload in node.js and it works perfectly. However, as the Azure function app doesn't support req.pipe and other stream handlers, multer is not working.

I wrote a new function app using [parse-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart), i am able to get the zip data on the server but the file is corrupt and there's a slight difference in size from the source zip file. I tried the same with a png with the same result.

Here's the relevant Angular client code:

```
uploadFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<Array<MyDataEntity>> {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('package', fileToUpload, fileToUpload['name']);
    return this.httpClient.post<Array<MyDataEntity>>(
      environment.serverUri + '/api/upload',
      formData
    );
  }
```

and node.js server code (running as Azure function):

```
var multipart = require("parse-multipart");
const fs = require('fs');

const INPUT_DIRECTORY = 'packages/input';
const OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = 'packages/output';

module.exports = function (context, req, res) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (!req.body) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    else {
        var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body, 'binary');
        context.log('file length: ' + bodyBuffer.length);
        // get boundary for multipart data e.g. ------WebKitFormBoundaryDtbT5UpPj83kllfw
        var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
        context.log('file boundary: ' + boundary);
        // parse the body
        var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);

        const archiveFilePath = __dirname + '/' + INPUT_DIRECTORY + '/' + parts[0].filename;
        // write buffer to file
        fs.writeFile(archiveFilePath, new Buffer(parts[0].data), 'binary', (err) => {
            context.log('Archive file path: ' + archiveFilePath);
            if (err) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 404,
                    body: "Failed to save the package"
                };
            }
        });
        context.res = { body : { name : parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data: parts[0].data.length}};
    }

    context.done();
};
```

Output sample:

> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.799 [Info] Function started (Id=9cdd063a-75b2-4738-a15a-3031893beddd)
>
> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.799 [Info] JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
>
> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.799 [Info] file length: 345
>
> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.799 [Info] file boundary: ----WebKitFormBoundarysae4JeoqAeEmVoim
>
> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.848 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=9cdd063a-75b2-4738-a15a-3031893beddd, Duration=58ms)
>
> 2018-08-08T08:57:33.878 [Info] Archive file path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\UploadPackage/packages/input/something.zip

I tried changing the encoding type for the buffer, i get different buffer sizes for different encoding types but none produces a correct output file:

```
var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body, 'binary');
var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body, 'utf8');
var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
```

etc...

Comment: Do you have [`"dataType": "binary"`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings.md#binding-datatype-property) in your function.json?

Comment: i didn't, but i just added it with the same result. My original zip file is 1,409,660 bytes in size but the uploaded zip is 1,329,450 in size.

Comment: Not sure if multipart works. Did you try uploading as `application/octet-stream`? That should work. See this as well (base64 encoding the payload before calling the function) -- https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express/issues/8

Comment: Need to try with application/octet-stream. I tried changing to Azure function v2.0+ as it fixed a bug in v1 but as soon as i change the version to v2.0+ (i.e. beta in Azure function app settings), the function stops working. Will try out the solutions you have given in a day or two

Comment: Well, we decided to ditch Azure functions for this one as we need the same app to run on cloud as well as embedded as it will be difficult to maintain the same code base for both in case we use Azure functions. For now, i have deployed the same multer based code to Azure Container Instance using docker on a Linux based 100 MB image.

Comment: BTW, base64 encoding should work, this article gives a nice example about the same: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/10/07/image-uploading-with-azure-functions-node-js-and-angular-4/